# How to iterate through an array of names and assign each name as a value of a property in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have this array: `var arrayCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];`

How can I iterate through it, and assign each car as the value of the property `Name` in an object with this description: `var objectCars = {Name: *insert car*, id: 1234};`.

In the end there should be 3 object. All called objectCars, but the value of **Name** should be different.

Here is my code, which obviously isn't working:

```js
var arrayCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

arrayCars.forEach(function(){
  var objectCars = {Name: arrayCars, id:1234};
  //Here I am sending that object to a database. No need to worry about that
});
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote to do this and explain specifically what isn't working correctly and exactly why/what is confusing to you.

Comment: do you know how to do a for loop?

Comment: Please check out my updated question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter in `forEach` callback is current value in array loop so you can use it as your object `name` value.

```js
var arrayCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

arrayCars.forEach(function(car) {
  var objectCars = {Name: car, id:1234};
  console.log(objectCars)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map()`

```js
var arrayCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"].map(c=>({
  Name: c,
  id: 1234
}));

console.log(arrayCars);
```